# Twitter V2 API is not working with bearer token received from APP API keys

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to use Twitter V2 APIs. I've been subscribed to free tier. According to documentation I can use /tweets & /users/me endpoints only. And I'm trying endpoint /users/me with bearer token received from API keys section. But it's showing oauth exception. Do I need to use any other token ?
Or will this work with basic/pro version?

Actual error I'm getting is:

`{"client_id":"27915705","detail":"When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.","registration_url":"https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview","title":"Client Forbidden","required_enrollment":"Appropriate Level of API Access","reason":"client-not-enrolled","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"}`

I setup oauth in app but still same issue is there.

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?